# adding a div to css multiple columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns

Is this possible?

I have, let's say, 15 divs distributed 3 each on a 5 columns multiple column CSS layout. I also have the equivalent responsive code to fluidly change the number of columns based on display size.

Now, how can I add a div say between 12 and 13th div, programatically? Is there a way to get the position of the divs in a multiple columns css flow? Similar to adding something to a matrix(x.y).

Comment: so are you trying to dynamically add a div during runtime?

Comment: Possible help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/javascript-create-div-and-append-div-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine some sort of language besides css would have to be implemented, like javascript. Here are some links i found about dynamically(during run time) adding a div/form.

Possible help

- [Create <div> and append <div> dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/javascript-create-div-and-append-div-dynamically)
- http://www.formget.com/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-using-javascript/

Comment: I have appended div during runtime. However, what I am looking for is, say, I have already loaded the page in 5 columns. Now through other user action another content for another div is added to the db and I want to dynamically refresh that to a certain column, and position. I am wondering if there is a way to id the column, row for the divs. and then insert top of the third column. not sure if I am explaining it clearly.

Comment: I think it's explained in one of those links, the DIV's are ID'd and you can check their ID   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170774/check-if-a-div-id-exists-with-jquery

Comment: Since the time I asked this, I changed the requirement and I am now handling this different. Nevertheless I will try it out for future reference and project use. Thank you!